# unable to find sdk 'iphoneos11.2'

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10

IDE: Xcode10

OS: 10.13.6

A compiler error

Showing Recent Messages
Build system information
error: unable to find sdk 'iphoneos11.2' (in target 'xxx')

The project built on Xcode 9.4 / OS 10.13.4. Only after updating did the project build start failing.

[image: Screenshot of error in Xcode]

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Click on your target

Click **Build Settings**

Under the **Base SDK** row, change the value to **iOS** (or whatever platform you are building for).

[image: Screenshot of Xcode Build Settings]

Comment: Working for me. Thank you Michael Sacks.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem and fixed it by going to Build Settings, Basic; the Base SDK was set to "11.4 (SDK not found)" ; I changed it to iOS and that fixed it.